# Java: implementation of notification provider vs. hashCode-driven Map

Tags: java, equals, listener, hashcode, weak-references

I have implemented abstract generic provider for notification bunch of generic listeners `E`, descendants have to override `notifyListener(E)` with specific notification code. For backing list of listeners I choose `WeakHashMap<K,V>`. Listeners must be held as weak references:

```
abstract public class NotificationProvider<E> {

    private Map<E, Object> listeners = new WeakHashMap<E, Object>();

    public addListener(E listener) {
        listeners.put(listener, null);
    }

    public void notifyListeners() {
        for (E listener: listeners.keySet())
            notifyListener(listener);
    }

    abstract protected void notifyListener(E listener);
}
```

Typical use:

```
    NotificationProvider<MyListener> provider;
    provider = new NotificationProvider<MyListener>() {
        @Override
        protected void notifyListener(MyListener listener) {
            listener.myNotification();
        }
    }
    provider.addListener(myListener1);
    provider.addListener(myListener2);
    provider.notifyListeners();
```

Everything works well, but when I need `AbstractList` descendant class as listener, backing `WeakHashMap` accepts only one listener instance! It's clear -- methods `hashCode()` and `equals()` on listeners return same value for all of instances (empty lists), so `WeakHashMap.put` only replace previously added listener.

```
    public class MyList extends AbstractList<MyItem> {
        // some implementation
    }
    NotificationProvider<MyList> provider;
    provider = new NotificationProvider<MyList>() {
        @Override
        protected void notifyListener(MyList listener) {
            // some implementation
        }
    }
    MyList list1 = new MyList();
    MyList list2 = new MyList();
    provider.addListener(list1);
    provider.addListener(list2); 
    provider.notifyListeners();  // only list2 instance is notified
```

What is the best solution?

1. use another non-hashCode backing collection -- but `WeakHashMap` is so sweet for me, because automatically managing weak references for me
2. use non-generic listener, for example abstract class with simple `equals() { return (this == object); }` implementation -- but this is not so flexible
3. use some wrapper for listeners with simple equals() -- but this wrapper cannot be transparent to `addListener(E)` caller due to weak references

Another ideas?

Comment: To be sure I understand the problem: are you trying to pass an AbstractList to your addListener() ?

Comment: No, I have descendant of AbstractList (in-fact it is AbstractListDecorator descendant) which implements some specific interface and this interface is listener class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WeakHashMap` is kind of broken. It uses weak keys, but it doesn't use identity hashing. Unless the `equals()` and `hashCode()` of your key type use "identity", you shouldn't use `WeakHashMap`. Instead you need something that's a combination of `WeakHashMap` and `IdentityHashMap`.

One possibility is to use [MapMaker](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) from Google Collections. It automatically uses identity hashes/equality for keys if the keys are weak or soft. eg:

```
ConcurrentMap<K, V> myMap = new MapMaker().weakKeys().makeMap();
```

Comment: for completeness: finally I have used `ReferenceIdentityMap` of apache.commons.collections15, see http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sourceforge/collections/collections-generic/4.01/collections-generic-4.01-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/commons/collections15/map/ReferenceIdentityMap.html.

Comment: Thank you, I have been looking for this for ages!!! I would give more thumbs up if I could! :)

Answer (score 1):

The crux of the problem seems to be that your listener implementation is subclassing `AbstractList`, but not overriding `equals()` / `hashCode()`.  I would strongly recommend against this type of inheritance (implementation inheritance) as it violates OO-principles (principle of polymorphic substitutability).

It would be far better to implement a custom listener class that possibly references an `AbstractList` if it requires one, and that also provides its own `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations.

Comment: In my case original `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations inherited from `AbstractList` are useful. Use of MyList as listener is only secondary use. What I wanted was bullet-proof implementation of NotificationProvider.  
But agree that use of `equals()` and `hashCode()` must be identical across all project...